# What kind of wire would i need to carry 20 amps 100 feet underground

Tags: wiring, wire

Have an existing underground circuit that goes from the house to the end of the back yard. It's about 40 years old, and I have no idea what shape the wire is in, but it still works. I'm thinking about build a shed at the end of the yard to use as a woodshop. I don't want to actually wire the building up, but I was thinking of running a new line underground. What would I need to run a 20 amp line around 100 feet underground.

Comment: 100ft underground? 30M? That is quiet the hole you are digging.
You sure you don't mean  100cm? 100cm is doable (barely) with a trench digging shovel (in the right soil, if you are lucky). 100mm seems reasonable. 30m is some serious earth moving

Comment: @Oxinabox, I think it's safe to assume he means 100' linear feet, not 100' deep.

Comment: You say a *"20A line"*, but what is the load?

Comment: @SpeedyPetey ooooooooooooooooooohh that makes more sense

Comment: Yes I mean underground, for 100 feet, not 100 feet underground .... and 110 volts not 220

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Wire size

You can use a calculator like http://wiresizecalculator.net/ to figure this out.

Keep in mind that the distance is not just the distance underground, but the entire wire distance from the panel to the receptacle/switch/fixture.

For 140', you'll need #6 copper or #4 aluminum.

### Burial depth

For a 120V, 20A circuit, protected by GFCI, in residential use, using direct-burial rated wire (UF), the minimum depth requirement is 12".

See also:

- [What is the best way to run underground electrical and low voltage in the same trench?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/42168/157)
- [How do I run a wire underground to an outdoor post lamp?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/a/5520/157)

Comment: Do you know if I can run that wire inside conduit? would rather make it as weatherproof as possible if I'm going to the trouble of digging the trench

Comment: @user379468 Yes, so long as it's "wet-rated" cable (eg: THWN or UF). Regular NM (or THHN) is not allowed underground, even in waterproof conduit.